# Optimizing HTML5 Animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a HTML5 animation that uses a canvas of size 900x520. However ~60% of the canvas is not utilized in the most general case. If some of the parameters of the animation are varied, then the whole canvas is utilized which is the reason why I pegged the maximum canvas size to `W:900px` and `H:520px`.

When a user opens the page with this HTML5 canvas, a general case is considered and only 280x280 at the center of the HTML5 canvas is used. As per my knowledge though I'm not using the other 60% of the canvas is not used but is rendered every time which is causing the animation to slow down, *especially on tablets and mobile phones* (Most of my intended users are tablets / mobile users). So, I would like to know if there are any techniques to render only a set of pixels everytime (say 300x300 at the center of the canvas) ? Are there any workaround solutions ?

I'm already using `RequestAnimationFrame` (However, I want some more optimization)

Comment: Can't you resize the canvas ?

Comment: I have taken 900x520 as fixed size and positioned my animation in the center. My animation is dependent on certain mathematical equations, which are translated to pixels (Based on my canvas size of 900x520) for proper animation, so I cannot probably resize the canvas !!!

Comment: It's almost impossible to help optimize code we haven't seen, but in general you can optimize canvas drawing by redrawing the smallest area of the canvas as possible--redraw only the portion that has changed instead of the whole canvas.

Comment: I'd suggest using two canvases. Set the working canvas, which should be hidden from view, to dimensions 900 x 520 and do all your drawing work on it. Set the second, visible canvas to the required dimensions eg 300 x 300 and display it. At the end of each animation tick, copy the invisible canvas over to the visible canvas using the canvas drawImage() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing i would try is to use the clip() function. It slows down the drawing, but in your case it might be faster to check first against a clip since 60% of the time the clipping will quit the drawing.

Second thing to try is to handle clipping by yourself :  handle a viewport object ( center x, center y, width, height ) and exclude unseen object with simple bounding box testing. Rq : Maybe the way you draw your scene allows for easy optimisation.

3) do not define a canvas bigger than the screen : rather define it at max size, and keep track of an offset, like with a viewPort object. And to avoid re-writing all your draw code, just use save/translate/restore before/after your old methods.  For the clipping on this canvas, refer to 1) :-)

4) you can reduce graphic strain on mobile by using css scaling. Even if scaling reduces performances, on mobiles it is faster to draw on smaller canvas with a css scale than to draw full resolution with no scale.
So you have to set canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height to some wise values, and you can set canvas.width and canvas.height to the setting that allows for the right performance.